# Convergence of the sum $\sum \frac {1}{(\log n)^{n^p}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck on this question. I thought about using $\sum a_{2^k} 2^k$ but I am not really sure how to proceed with the logarithms after. Thank you.

Comment: I don`t understand how you get that equality

Comment: @CheeHan: that equality does not seem to be valid...

Comment: What exactly are $n$ and $p$ ?

Comment: @StephenG $p \ge 0$ and n is regular indexing number (in N)

Comment: $p$ positive real or integer or something else ?

Comment: @StephenG it is not specified, the answer will depend on its value

Comment: @StephenG From OP previous comment, $p \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Try, as suggested in the OP, the $\sum 2^ka_{2^k}$ test.

Now, for $p>1$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k a_{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \big(\log (2^k)\big)^{-2^{kp}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{ (k\log 2)^{2^{kp}}}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k\frac{\log 2}{2^{1/p}})^{2^{kp}}}\le
\frac{2^{1/p}}{\log 2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{2^{kp}}} 
$$
But $k^{2^{kp}}>k^2$, for $k>1/p$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {1}{(\log n)^{n^p}}=e^{-n^p\log \log n}$$

Since $p>0$,

$${n^p\log\log n\geq n^p}$$

$$0\leq e^{-n^p\log \log n}\leq e^{-n^p}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I fixed some of the formatting issues and replaced "$\ln$" with "$\log$" to be consistent; I hope that's okay.

Comment: You're welcome!